# Poor text contrast (black on blue) for moderator pills

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, user-interface

A recent deployment changed the text colours within the staff and moderator pill indicators on profile pages to black/dark gray - this makes it hard to read. Previously the text colour was white, could this change be reverted?

[image]

Tested with userscripts disabled, on
Win 10, Chrome Version 80.0.3987.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: _“A fix will be deployed soon. Thanks for pointing it out!”_ — [Text color on “Moderator” and “Staff” badges is hard to read](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345018/289905).

Comment: Hmm, that was a day ago.

Comment: Did they let go of 6 to 8 weeks?

Comment: @SamuelLiew ["Soon"](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=soon%20%28tm%29)

Comment: Same issue in Opera (Not that I expected a different result).

Answer (score 9):

Fixed! Sorry the deploy took a second. We often have things of way higher priority that need to get merged and deployed before a little visual bug, as I'm sure y'all understand